# Communication between SignalR and Arduino using WebSocket

Tags: c#, websocket, arduino, signalr, asp.net-web-api2

I need a realtime data connection between an embedded device(arduino for now) and a web application, I am considering using SignalR for this and just forcing websocket method on it, I can connect to a test websocket server from my device but will it be the same when using SignalR as server or should I consider another alternatives?